# C# OpenGL Window is Lagging

Tags: c#, opengl, window, lag, opentk

I'm having a problem: When I create a window in OpenGL, using C#, my window starts to lag, and I cannot use the window (I cannot close, minimize, resize, etc.). And when I hover my mouse inside the window, my cursor becomes that blue wheel, meaning it's lagging. How can I fix it?

It's worth saying that I'm using OpenGL and OpenTK to display and use the window however I want.

This is my code for generating the window:

First, this is the “GameLoop” class, everything related to the game itself is derived from this class, it contains some abstract classes that I can override, so it's really useful.

```
public abstract class GameLoop
{
    public GameWindow window;
    public Vector2Int windowSize = new Vector2Int(1280, 768);

    public void Run()
    { 
        OnInitialize();

        WindowManager.CreateWindow(windowSize.x, windowSize.y, "Engine", out window);
        
        OnLoad();

        while (WindowManager.IsRunning)
        {
            OnUpdate();
            OnRender();
        }

        OnCloseWindow();
    }
    
    protected abstract void OnInitialize();
    protected abstract void OnLoad();
    protected abstract void OnUpdate();
    protected abstract void OnRender();
    protected abstract void OnCloseWindow();
}

class RunGameLoop
{
    static void Main()
    {
        GameLoop loop = new EngineWindow();
        loop.Run();
    }
}
```

Secondly, I have this method in another class that is responsible for creating the window itself:

```
public static void CreateWindow(int width, int height, string title, out GameWindow window)
{
    window = new GameWindow(GameWindowSettings.Default, NativeWindowSettings.Default);

    Vector2Int res = new Vector2Int(width, height);
    //windowSize = res;

    IsRunning = true;

    window.CenterWindow(Vector2Int.ToVec2i(res));
    window.Title = title;
}
```

And finally, I have the main class, where I can use OpenGL and make my project:

```
public class EngineWindow : GameLoop
{
    protected override void OnInitialize()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("On Initialize");
    }

    protected override void OnLoad()
    {
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Lighting);

        GL.ClearColor(Color.ToColor4(BackColor));

        GL.Viewport(0, 0, windowSize.x, windowSize.y);

        CreateMesh(cubeMesh);
    }

    protected override void OnUpdate()
    {
        
    }

    protected override void OnRender()
    {
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

        angle += Time.deltaTime;

        SetupViewport(sceneCamera);
        RenderMesh(cubeMesh);

        ControllCamera(sceneCamera);

        GL.CullFace(CullFaceMode.Back);

        GL.Finish();

        window.SwapBuffers();           
    }

    protected override void OnCloseWindow()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Ended");
        // Clean up
        GL.DeleteProgram(program);
        GL.DeleteBuffers(1, ref vbo);
        GL.DeleteVertexArrays(1, ref vao);
    }
}
```

But, the issue is that when the window is created, it starts up fine, but becomes extremely laggy and I can't use the window.

What might be the issue, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try removing `GL.Clear(). ` You most likely don't need it according to the docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.Clear.html. Also you call SetupViewport every single frame, is this really needed? Maybe you can change that to call it in some event which listens to window size changes.

Comment: @Joost00719 no, I cannot remove that. If I remove the problem persists and there's no background nor depth.  About the SetupViewport, I must call it every frame bacause it's responsable for displaying things in the screen. (Also it does not fix my problem.)
Edit: Also, I'm not using Unity, this is pure C# with OpenGL and OpenTK

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that I'm not calling "base.OnUpdateFrame(args);". The original method is: "
protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs args){
    base.OnUpdateFrame(args);
}
"

Comment: How could I do that in a class that's not derived from GameWindow?